# iPhone Email app launch url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The url to launch email and start a new email on an iphone is "mailto://someone@somwhere.com".  I just want to launch the email app, dropping the user at the main menu, or inbox.

"mailto:" starts composing a new blank email

I've tried "mail:", "email:" and a few others.  Is there no way to just launch the email app?

Comment: I think the answer is just "no".  I haven't accepted an answer because I think their justifications are all wrong.  If someone would just post "No, you can't" I'll accept that.

Comment: In case you miss it, there's an [excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24953719/2547229) below, linking to [this article](https://medium.com/@vijayssundaram/how-to-deep-link-to-ios-7-mail-6c212bc79bd9). You can open the mail app. You can even open it _on_ your specific sign up response email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, since the whole idea of the url schemes is to launch another app given some context in your own app. Watch a specific YouTube vid, write an email, etc.

in addition, this sounds like a weird requirement - why would you just want to send them to their email client without having them compose an email?

Comment: His app probably says, "Check your email to complete registration" or something.

Comment: Ah, good point. Even if this is the case though, I'd say the right design is to assume that the user is probably well aware of how to check their email on their iPhone. They know when the notification comes or perhaps even any latency that they experience, if they don't have push email on.

Comment: Bingo.  And yes, we decided to just let them figure it out, but I thought it was still worth asking out of curiosity.

Comment: As far as your answer, I don't think your argument is correct.  The idea of url schemes is to launch apps... context is not implied.

Check out this list of known url schemes for examples of plenty that don't take parameters -- http://applookup.com/

Answer (score 10):

This is now possible since iOS 7 using message ID tricks. Use the URL `message:<messageID>` with a dummy Message ID (such as 0).

See this [blog post](https://medium.com/@vijayssundaram/how-to-deep-link-to-ios-7-mail-6c212bc79bd9) for more info :

> A happy by-product of this URL scheme and behavior is that you can use a dummy string for the message-id to just launch the Mail app without deep linking to a specific email. This can enable scenarios where an app may want to launch the user directly into their inbox e.g. to verify their email address to complete the signup process.

Comment: This is awesome, and a great answer. You could presumably use a UUID as the message ID and either tell that to your server backend when requesting a sign in link, or simply use a fixed id. Then you can jump directly in to the email. Maybe walk the user through from tutorial before giving them the "open email" button to give the email time to turn up.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using an invalid email address?  Something like `mailto://!!!`?

Comment: Interesting thought.  I'll try it when I get a chance.  I'm guessing that even if it works, it will throw the user a notice though.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation (highlight added).

> The mailto scheme is used to launch the Mail application and open the
>   email compose sheet. **When specifying a mailto URL, you must provide the
>   target email address.**

So it does not appear you can do what you want.

-t

Comment: The mailto:// scheme can not do what I want, but that doesn't mean the app hasn't registered another url scheme that can.

Comment: Unless you can find that URL scheme documented in the SDK documentation - using it would be a violation of your developer agreement and your App would be rejected.

I don't see any other URL schemes registered for email in the SDK documentation. Sorry.

Comment: Hmmm would it?  Using other applications' url schemes isn't a violation of the TOS.  I can't seem to find it, but if you can cite me the part of the agreement or apple docs that says that, I'd be happy to accept yours as the answer to my question.  Thanks Tim.

Comment: From the Developer Agreement: 3.3.1 Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs.

Comment: I appreciate the legwork Tim, and I voted you up, but I'm pretty certain that using a registered url scheme, advertised or not, doesn't fall into the category of a private API.  They reject for some pretty crazy reasons, but I just can't envision them rejecting for that one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

;)

Along the lines of what Tim said, since the handling of the URL is automatic and trying to degrade the URL to where the Mail app somehow throws up and just shows the menu could give undesirable results in App Review or in future OS/Mail App versions, you might not like it even if you make it work. You might want it, but that's another thing :)

If you want to 'just start the app', look here. http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html