# How to open iphone mail application from my own application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

i am working on signup feature. In this feature when the user create account successfully. i am asking him or her to activate his account.
i want to open the mail application of iphone if user say yes.
now my question is simple how to open mail application from my own application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942689/iphone-email-app-launch-url

Comment: There's an excellent answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24953719/2547229) that links to [this article](https://medium.com/@vijayssundaram/how-to-deep-link-to-ios-7-mail-6c212bc79bd9). You can directly open the App, and you can even open a specific email (provided Apple don't remove the API, anyway).

Comment: If somebody would like to open compose email inside app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862523/objective-c-send-email-without-leaving-app

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
#define URLEMail @"mailto:sb@sw.com?subject=title&body=content"

 NSString *url = [URLEMail stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]; 
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Just FYI, your code has a semantical error. I think you meant to say `NSString *url = [URLEMail stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: Any tips on how to try this in the simulator?

Answer (score 11):

Try this out.

```
-(void)launchMailAppOnDevice
{
    NSString *recipients = @"mailto:myemail@gmail.com?subject=subjecthere";
    NSString *body = @"&body=bodyHere";

    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

Comment: not works :(
and i am not want to send email i want to check email 
thats y i want open native mail app of iphone

Comment: just minor mistake,this is right string NSString *recipients = @"mailto:myemail@gmail.com?subject=subjecthere";

Answer (score 8):

stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding and openURL are deprecated.

Now use this:

```
#define URLEMail @"mailto:sb@sw.com?subject=title&body=content"

NSString * encodedString = [URLEMail stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];

UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [application openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: encodedString] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

Ahoy!

The long and short of it is; you can't.

You can create an email compose view for the purpose of sending emails (see [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)), but you cannot open applications arbitrarily without a purpose.

See this previous post for clarification: [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

Really though, it's not much effort for the user to close your app and open Mail so I wouldn't worry too much about it anyway.